# Visual Studio - How to make the autocomplete suggestions appear?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Is there a shortcut to get the autocomplete suggestions instead of waiting for it to appear when writing something? 
 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> Standard Visual Studio hotkey if you need to see contextual suggestions in code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> It's a new feature with smart suggestions and code generation.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> If you use [JetBrains Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

See the list of all default Visual Studio shortcuts [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the hotkey is control-space.

Answer (score 1):

By pressing Ctrl + Space it will display all the suggestions in Visual Studio